# Is it possible to use NServiceBus with Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, architecture, nservicebus, azure-service-fabric

The way I see it, Azure Service Fabric would maintain the cluster of microservices, and NServiceBus would facilitate the communication between services. I see next to no documentation online about this combination, so I am curious if I am fundamentally mistaken in how these two things work.

Answer (score 9):

You can perfectly run nservicebus inside service fabric, just use the self hosting approach together with the Azure Service Bus transport and potentially the azure storage persistence for sagas.

I've taken note of your request to document this here: https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/issues/2328

Comment: NServiceBus can be a point of failure which means you can lose data. Instead, you can use the reliable services to process those messages reliably via reliable dictionaries/queues.

Comment: NServiceBus does not lose messages, it uses azure servicebus under the hood to ensure reliable message exchange. Furthermore it's impossible to use reliable queues for message exchange today as only 1 writer is allowed per partition, so you can only use it inside a process and not in between processes as both need to write/delete. Exposing the queue over the native communication mechanism is also not an option if you want reliability as that itself has no guaranteed delivery semantics.(if any of the internal mechanisms ever allows reliable message exchange, nservicebus will leverage those)

Comment: Reliable dictionaries and queues are usefull though as a storage mechanism inside the service, if you want to do that with nservicebus I have a spike here https://github.com/ParticularLabs/NServiceBus.ServiceFabric (albeit a bit old)

Comment: For communication between services inside the cluster and as long as my message(sizes) are manageable I would prefer to use the reliable queue/dictionary. That way the storage are close to the compute.

Comment: @alltej can you post a link to an example where this approach is used. Because afaik it is technically impossible to do it, only the master instance of a statefull service can write to the queue.

Comment: Thank you. Because Service Fabric requires .NET Core for web app services, does this not create issues with NServiceBus not supporting .NET Core yet?

Comment: @adam3039 I don't think Service Fabric mandates .NET Core, but I guess the default visual studio template for a web app in SF will be using .NET Core. It is possible to run nservicebus in a .NET Core app as long as it targets the correct runtime. Here is some documentation on the matter, https://docs.particular.net/samples/web/send-from-aspnetcore-webapi/ even though this one is IIS specific and not SF specific.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. Do you think you could expand your answer with a brief explanation of how you'd go about running NServiceBus within Azure Service fabric? Would it be hosted in a stateful service of its own? I'd like to know how I can achieve messaging between two stateless/stateful services.

Comment: NServicebus is a library that embeds in your process, it does not need it's own service to run in. It can be embedded in both stateless and stateful services. If you use Azure Service Bus as a transport between simple processing code than it may not need to store state at all (you can opt for the in memory persistence procider). If you need complex process coordination you will want to add a persistence provider for Saga's. In case of stateless this provider could be the azure storage one or nhibernate (on sql database). /1

Comment: Alternatively you could store saga data locally on the service fabric, similar to the sample in https://github.com/ParticularLabs/NServiceBus.ServiceFabric, in that case it must be a statefull service. /2

Comment: Using NServiceBus on Service Fabric doesn't sound so simple. By convention, Service Fabric is going to want to run multiple instances of a particular service so if you publish an event how do you prevent 5 instances of ThumbnailResizeService from handling it? You'd just want one instance of any particular service to handle the event.

Comment: @YvesGoeleven We are evaluating NServiceBus and Azure Service Bus.  We have already built a POC utilizing Azure Service Bus queues backed by Service Fabric Stateful services. It works well. However, I'm trying to find the area where NServiceBus fits into this solution and provides additional value.  Do you have any recommendations?